# Конкурс завершится через завтра

Tags: дефект, локализация, конкурс

Конкурс не может завершиться через завтра, он может завершиться просто завтра или через 1 день (кстати, это не синонимы). Однако, в "плашке" о конкурсе написано именно так:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там даты подставляются в строку вида: `**The [bounty]($BountyHelpUrl$) expires $timeLeftPreSpan$$timeLeft$$postSpan$**`. Если кто-то может придумать, как это лучше локализовать, то можно поменять)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik А как это выглядит в английской версии? Неужто тоже "after tomorrow"?

Comment: @Yaant в английской версии либо expires in (N hours, N days), либо expires tomorrow. То есть как-то определяется нужен ли предлог или нет.

Comment: @insolor Воот. То есть, надо выяснить, как формируется $timeLeftPrespan$.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik там же есть аналогичная строка, в которой все нормально: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13900 "через" вообще не должно фигурировать в строке, так как оно включено в переменную timeLeft

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight сложно сказать. Осложняется тем, что не ясно, где ещё строки используются кроме этого места.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Что тут сложного? Специально открыл конкурс для проверки, оказалось, когда число в днях, "через" дублируется: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515309/ `Конкурс завершится через через 7 дней.`

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, по твоей ссылке вижу `Срок конкурса истекает через 7 дней.` Куда смотреть-то надо?

Comment: @Qwertiy смотреть надо сюда: https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=The%20%5C%5Bbounty%5C%5D Там, видимо, отличаются сообщения для автора конкурса и для остальных, и ошибка видна только автору.

Comment: @Qwertiy проблемная надпись отображается, когда ты сам назначил конкурс: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7cWD.png

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight сорри, с утра туплю. Можете предложить новый перевод, приму)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik предложил: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14250

Answer (score 2):

Новую строку утвердили: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14250

Теперь "через" будет отображаться только когда срок представлен числом в днях/часах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]